# how we prevent reading the next offset if the previous offset has not been committed yet in kafka - High Level Consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, php-rdkafka

I'm new in kafka. Now, i'm trying to commit kafka message explicitly like if my all mysql operation successful then i'll commit the record but kafka reads next offset if the previous offset has not been committed yet.

Codes are following:

```
`$conf = new \RdKafka\Conf();
$conf->set('group.id', $groupId);
$conf->set('metadata.broker.list', $brokers);
$conf->set('auto.offset.reset', 'earliest');
$conf->set('enable.auto.commit', 'true');
$conf->set('enable.auto.offset.store', 'false');
$conf->set('auto.commit.interval.ms', 100);
$conf->set('enable.partition.eof', 'true');

$consumer = new \RdKafka\KafkaConsumer($conf);
$consumer->subscribe($subscriptionArr);

$this->logger->info("Waiting for partition assignment... (make take some time when quickly re-joining the group after leaving it.)", [$groupId, $brokers, $subscriptionArr]);
$tmp=0;
//let add some counters so at least we have some numbers of topics we processed...
$search_array=[];
while ($active) {
    $message = $consumer->consume(120*1000);
    
    if ($this->debug) {
        $active = false;
    }
    
    switch ($message->err) {
        case RD_KAFKA_RESP_ERR_NO_ERROR:
            $topic_name = $message->topic_name;
            $timestamp = $message->timestamp;
            $payload = $message->payload;
            $message_offset = $message->offset;
            $partition = $message->partition;
            $timeoutMs = 10000000;
            
            $this->logger->info("topic partition details ", [$partition]);

            $topic = $consumer->newTopic($topic_name);
            $topicPartition = new \RdKafka\TopicPartition($topic_name, $partition);
            $this->logger->info("topic partitions",[$topicPartition]);
            $partition_id = $topicPartition->getPartition();
            $this->logger->info("topic partitions",[$partition_id]);
            $topicPartitionsWithOffsets = $consumer->getCommittedOffsets([$topicPartition], $timeoutMs);
            $queryExecutionStatus = $this->sinkConnector->injectKafka($topic_name, $payload, $timestamp);

            $this->logger->info($topic_name." query execution status",[$queryExecutionStatus]);
            $this->logger->info("before commited offset ", [$topicPartitionsWithOffsets]);
            if ($queryExecutionStatus == 1) {
                if (array_key_exists($topic_name, $search_array) ) {
                    $search_array[$topic_name] = $search_array[$topic_name] + 1;
                } else {
                    // set initial value of the counter
                    $search_array[$topic_name]=1;
                }
                $this->logger->info("manually commited offset of topic ".$topic_name, [$message_offset]);  

                $topic->offsetStore($message->partition, $message_offset);
                $storeOffset = $topicPartition->getOffset();
                $this->logger->info("commited offset ", [$storeOffset]);
            } else {
                $this->logger->warning("Warning: Message not inserted/updated ".$topic_name, [$message_offset]);
            }  
            break;
        case RD_KAFKA_RESP_ERR__PARTITION_EOF:
            $this->logger->notice("No more messages on partition; will wait for more", [$search_array]);
            
            $tmp++;
            $search_array=[];
            break;
        case RD_KAFKA_RESP_ERR__TIMED_OUT:
            //on-timeouts.we.can.rest.the.cpu.of.the.machine.
            $this->logger->notice("Timed out", [$tmp]);
            
            $active = false;
            break;
        default:
            $this->logger->warning("Warning: Kafka-Exception", [message=>$message->errstr(), error=> $message->err, count=> $tmp]);
            //throw new \Exception($message->errstr(), $message->err);
            $active = false;
            break;
    }
}
// flush and close the kafka-client and make sure it does not leave any open files...
$this->logger->notice("Disconnecting from the nodes and go to sleep mode");
//$consumer->commit(); //we dont have a no local offset stored...;) this forcefully lowers: ls /proc/$pid/fd/ | wc -l
$consumer->unsubscribe();
$consumer->close();
//force-closure.to.release.fopens
unset($consumer);
$consumer = null;`
```

I tried commit() of php rdkafka to commit it synchronously.  Also tried to change value of auto.commit.interval.ms configuration

Comment: One clarification there. Are you talking about the situation when a consumer (after the restart-like situation) starts consuming data not from the committed offset but from the last consumed one or it is when a consumer is in the process of consuming and it keeps getting new data by next offsets regardless a committed offset?

Comment: No. I'm not talking about restart situation. I'm talking about normal behaviour of Kafka. I think if we set auto.restore.offset false and auto.commit is also false. So, it should be pick (read) records which are not commited. Don't process next offset without commit previous or old offset

Comment: Please see my answer below, hopes it helps to find all answers to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Kafka has a Pull-based model, meaning consumers have full control over the data consumption and brokers play the role of data storage. Brokers have no knowledge about consumers and how many records were consumed by an arbitrary consumer, let's say all parameters for consuming are provided by a consumer.

There is a definition of a *last consumed offset* (current offset) and *last committed offset*. The values of these offsets are different. The *last consumed offset* usually is greater than the *last committed offset* and simply represents the offset value of the latest record that was consumed (for more details you can check a short article: https://www.learningjournal.guru/courses/kafka/kafka-foundation-training/offset-management/).
So the reason why your consumer keeps consume records is *last consumed offset*

As far as I know, to suspend a record consumption by an offset that is not committed you should "suspend" a consumer itself. In Java, there are `pause` and `resume` methods for that purpose, but your question is about PHP, so I did a little pick in Kafka docs for PHP but didn't find the explicit counterpart. Perhaps, you can check `rd_kafka_pause_partitions()` and `rd_kafka_resume_partitions()` (see https://idealo.github.io/php-rdkafka-ffi/api/RdKafka/FFI/Library/#rd_kafka_pause_partitions)

Answer (score 0):

By defalut, kafka commits automatically, you should set enable.auto.commit to false.

```
set('enable.auto.commit', 'false');
```

Comment: thanks for response but still commit highest offset still previous one has not been commited. set (enable.auto.commit, false)